# Is there a database of interlinear glosses of subordination-examples?

Tags: linguistic-typology, interlinear-gloss

I'm currently investigating the typology of subordination, or to be more precise adverbial subordination, and would like to see the data that the existing analyses, like for instance Cristofaro (2005) *Subordination*, are based on. Is there already an existing, accessible collection of interlinear glosses or must I keep on hunting down reference-grammars? Primarily examples of non-Indo European languages are of interest.

Comment: You're probably gonna have to keep hunting down reference grammars.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you try searching for the COMPLEMENTIZER tag on ODIN, the "Online Database of Interlinear Text." But it would appear to be broken at the moment. :( http://www.csufresno.edu/odin/

Comment: @pat Oooh, ooh, hadn't heard of ODIN!

Answer (score 1):

I know WALS (World Atlas of Linguistic Typolology) www.wals.info has a chapter on the "Order of Adverbial Subordinator and Clause" http://wals.info/feature/

You could use this as a starting point because you know that all 660 languages in this survey cover a good area and genetic spread - and WALS almost always point you to a reference grammar.

Might take some of the grunt-work out of your task!